# Jenkins JDepend Plugin reports JAR classes

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am using 1.467 and Jenkins JDepend plugin 1.2.3.
When I build, it generates the JDepend report.
No problem.

THe problem is that I get reports on classes like:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload
org.hibernate.ejb
```

Packages report on classes that I didn't write.
How I configure this so that it JDepend only run on classes that I write?

```
com.mycompany.myproject
```

for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it to work by setting the goal to "jdepend:generate" and setting the Pre-generated JDepend file to "target/jdepend-report.xml"

Answer (score 0):

[JDepend Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jdepend-maven-plugin/) looks quite old and seems to be in beta.  It does not support a way to exclude packages/classes.  I assume [jenkins JDepend Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JDepend+Plugin) uses the information from this to generate the report.

[JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) itself provides [options](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html#customize) to include/exclude classes/packages from analysis. JDepend [ant task](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html#ant) provides support for this as well.

One possibility would be to use jdepend ant task using [maven antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) (or directly invoke jdepend using [maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)) to do the analysis and specify the report file to jenkins plugin for reporting.